# Can sails populate assocations of more that one level deep?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm messing around with the v0.10 release of sails, and I have come across a puzzling issue. I have a relationship with the app I'm building which is a simple quiz app. The issue arises around the structure of my models and associations:

Quiz -> Questions -> Answers

Quiz:

```
  attributes: {

    questions: {
        collection: 'Question',
        via: 'quiz'
    }

  }
```

Question:

```
  attributes: {

    answers: {
        collection: 'Answer',
        via: 'question'
    },
    quiz: { model: 'Quiz' }

  }
```

Answer:

```
  attributes: {

    question: { model: 'Question' }

  }
```

I've left out the rest of the model code for clarity.

Now the problems, when I retrieve the resource at api/quiz the questions are populated but there are no answers. I read somewhere that there is no nested model population in sails/waterline yet, is this really the case?

Even if I go to api/question then I get back the questions but without answers, in this case I wouldn't regard the answer as being nested. It seems that no matter what I do I cannot get sails to populate answers into questions, but it will always populate questions in quiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it seems that I was using sails 0.10.0 rc-7 once I upgraded to 0.10.5 the problems ceased

Answer (score 2):

It sure can. Here is an easy way to do it.

```
getPopulatedQuiz: function(quizId) {
  return Quiz.findOne(quizId)
  .populate('questions')
  .then(function(quiz) {
    return nestedPop(quiz, {
      questions: [
        'answers'
      ]
    }).then(function(quiz) {
      return quiz;
    });
  });
}
```

Make sure you require nestedPop.

```
var nestedPop = require('nested-pop');
```

You can find more information about it below.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nested-pop

Comment: How can I use your NPM module to get 5 levels associated data?